# Implicit conversion and functional operators

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

I'm studying functional operators and can't understand why code snippets like this compile:

```
class Pocket
{
    int value;
public:
    Pocket(int value) :value(value) {}
    int getValue() const
    {
        return value;
    }
    operator int() const
    {
        return value;
    }
    bool operator<(const Pocket & _Right) const
    {
        return value < _Right.value;
    }
};

int main() {
    Pocket mynumbers1[] = { 3, 9, 2, -4, 4 };
    Pocket mynumbers2[] = { 3, 9, 5, 0, 4 };
    vector<Pocket> v1(mynumbers1, mynumbers1 + 5);
    vector<Pocket> v2(mynumbers2, mynumbers2 + 5);
    vector<Pocket> v3(5, 0);
    transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v3.begin(), minus<Pocket>());
    return 0;
}
```

My reasoning is that when you call the `minus<Pocket>` operator inside `transform`, the whole thing would reduce to a subtraction between two `Pocket`s. As you can see, the class doesn't defines a proper `operator-`, only an `operator<`, which should be useless in this case, and a conversion to `int`, which shouldn't even be considered since both arguments are of the same type.

So what am I missing?

Comment: The compiler will deduce a possible conversion for `minus()` using the explicit cast operator of `Pocket`.

Comment: Where did you gather the user defined conversion isn't going to come into play?

Comment: _"and a conversion to `int`, which shouldn't even be considered since both arguments are of the same type"_ This statement is very unclear, can you elaborate more please why you think this should apply?

Comment: Your reasoning is incorrect - the compiler will use the user-defined conversion you have specified.   To demonstrate that, remove the `operator int` from the `Pocket` class - you will see that the code no longer compiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user-defined conversion function which makes the following initializations possible in your code:

```
Pocket mynumbers1[] = { 3, 9, 2, -4, 4 };
Pocket mynumbers2[] = { 3, 9, 5, 0, 4 };
```

will also be used by the compiler in the `transform` call when applying the `minus` to the given range :

```
transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v3.begin(), minus<Pocket>());
```

If you were to remove the `operator int() const` conversion function neither the initializations nor the transform would work.

However, if you were to make the conversion function `explicit`, it would work for initializations but not for the `transform`. See demo [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a66a0cac4b351ce7).

The relevant section in the standard for this:

> **15.3.2 Conversion functions [class.conv.fct]**
>   ...
>   2.  A conversion function may be explicit, in which case it is only considered as a user-defined conversion for direct-initialization. Otherwise, user-defined conversions are not restricted to use in assignments and initializations.